# Pulling in photos via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to pull in tagged photos of the current logged in profile. Got a session ID but it appears it's an empty array.

```
<?php 
$photos = $facebook->api('me/photos');
$number_of_photos = count($photos[data]);
?>

<?php for ($i=0; $i < $number_of_photos; $i++) :?>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos/<?php echo $photos[data][$i][url]; ?>"/>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

I'm aware this code is probably really awful, I'm new to PHP and just trying a few things.

Comment: Does print_r($photos) return anything?  Try visiting the API URL directly and see the results you get.

Comment: Nope. I'm following the example stuff on the facebook documentation as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by the documentation available [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) (scroll down to 'Connections'), in order to get user's photos she must have explicitly given you one of the following permissions:

- user_photo_video_tags
- friend_photo_video_tags
- user_photos
- friend_photos permissions

Comment: Thought I had them in. Thanks for the help.